# Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem using Laravel 5. When I run "php aritsan migrate", I got this error

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command? [y/N] y

[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

I could run the application, but when database connection needed, I got this error

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
could not find driver
in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 55
at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'mydb', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in MySqlConnector.php line 22
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Install the PDO driver on your server.

Comment: For PHP 7.4 on Windows 10 (x64) have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333044/laravel-migration-cannot-find-driver-when-using-sqlsrv-database-in-windows/65762068#65762068

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You should install PDO on your server.
Edit your php.ini (look at your `phpinfo()`, "Loaded Configuration File" line, to find the php.ini file path).
Find and uncomment the following line (remove the `;` character):

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Then, restart your Apache server.
For more information, please [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/pdo.installation.php).

Comment: First, follow the @user657309 answer to install mysql (given your php version, not especially php7.0)

Comment: If you're using php-fpm you need to restart it, apart from restarting web server (nginx/apache)

Answer (score 129):

Same thing happend to me after upgrading distro.

Running `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql` fixed it for me.

Comment: Not sure why this has been marked down. This worked fine for me whereas the accepted answer did not.

Comment: This is the first step, then activate PDO if needed. Take care of installing the mysql plugin for the right php version you're using, not especially the 7.0 (php -v)

Comment: I faced this error after replacing apache by nginx. I reinstalled php7.0-mysql after all and it worked like a charm.

Comment: In my case, I had already installed that and it was working for the command line (using the `artisan migrate` commands) but for some reason was still failing in the application. **I needed to restart apache!**

Comment: I would suggest running `php -v` first to see what version of PHP you are running, and then install the appropriate version

Comment: Thank you. It worked in ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, php7.4, laravel 3.2.0

Comment: In some cases (latest Debian I think) it's `php-mysql`

Answer (score 31):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 5.6.20

After too many problems, the below steps solved this for me:

1. find `php.ini` path via `phpinfo()`
2. uncomment

   ```
   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
   ```
3. add this line

   ```
   extension=pdo_mysql.so
   ```
4. then run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php-mysql
   ```

Comment: `.dll` files are used by Windows operating system and shouldn't have an effect. That's why you need the `.so` equivalent for Linux.

Comment: Thank you so much. After striving for hours, your solution worked for me.

Comment: Yes. That worked for the latest version: PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Answer (score 18):

It will depend of your php version. Check it running:

```
php -version
```

Now, according to your current version, run:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Answer (score 16):

`sudo apt-get update`

**For Mysql Database**

`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

**For PostgreSQL Database**

`sudo apt-get install php-pgsql`

**Then**

`php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the following command on Ubuntu and its working for me
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If your database is PostgreSQL and you have php7.2 you should run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-pgsql
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your amswer with some detail, ask questions in `comments` section.

Comment: sudo is for linux. what is for windows?

Answer (score 5):

Uncomment database line from php.ini file according to your database type

For MYSQL

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
```

For Postgres

```
;extension=pgsql
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have php8 installed on ubuntu 20.04, you can run this command

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I was running the migrate command not from inside the container where php was running. The extension was properly set there but not at my host machine.

Comment: Same here, i should have run the command from my docker shell.

Answer (score 1):

This did trick for me.

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

it will install **php-mysql** depending on the ***version of php*** you are using