# Laravel Intervention Image GD library extension

Tags: php, laravel

First of all, I am sorry if my question may be too vague. So, I will try to clarify my question as much as possible.

I am currently developing a Laravel application, and I am trying to use Intervention Image Facade. When I tried to use it to test an upload, I got the following error:-

```
NotSupportedException in Driver.php line 16: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
```

So, as I would try to do, I installed the GD library using `sudo apt-get install libgd3` and the php gd driver using `sudo apt-get php5.6-gd`. However, this did not work, and the same error keeps popping up in laravel. What have I clearly missed, and what should I follow next?

**Edit 1.**  I used the following command to see if php actually supports gd driver : - `php -i | grep -i --color gd`

The following result came: -

```
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.3
GD library Version => 2.2.3
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
GDM_LANG => en_US
GDMSESSION => ubuntu
_SERVER["GDM_LANG"] => en_US
_SERVER["GDMSESSION"] => ubuntu
```

Hope this helps even more.

**EDIT 2** Thanks to all who answered. I found my solution in Mayank Pandey's answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because the GD Library is missing on your server.

You must enable the library GD2.

Find your (proper) `php.ini` file, and then find the line:

`;extension=php_gd2.dll`, remove the semicolon in the front. `;` means the line is commented, so remove the comment)

The line should look like this:

`extension=php_gd2.dll`

Then restart apache and you are ready to go.

Comment: First  stop php artisan serve, if php artisan run. Then restart apache

Answer (score 36):

**This is because the GD Library is missing on your server For PHP 8.x**

Find your (proper) php.ini file, and then find the line:[image]

`;extension=gd`, remove the semicolon in the front. `;` means the line is commented, so remove the comment.

**The line should look like this:**

```
extension=gd
```

Then restart apache and you are ready to go.

**NOTE: If You are using php version <=7.x**

`;extension=php_gd2.dll`, itshould look like this:  `extension=php_gd2.dll`

Comment: You need to pass the following commands : 

#php artisan route:clear


#php artisan route:clear;

#php artisan optimize:clear

# source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK15tS1zrZ0

Answer (score 8):

**If using php 8**

1. go to xampp/php/php.ini and  find ;extension=gd as shown in image
2. replace ;extension=gd with extension=gd (just remove the ; and save)

[image]

3. finally restart apache.. thats all

Answer (score 7):

Install GD extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

For PHP 7.1 try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```

For PHP 7.2 try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

Then restart your server.

Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: I hope you had read the question, as I followed the above steps. I needed help afterward. But thank you for answering.

Comment: Restarting apache didn't work. I had to reboot the server for it to work.

Comment: Restarting apache didn't work because I was serving my laravel app using php artisan serve which uses a different .ini file. So you need to stop php artisan serve and start it again for changes to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

As @nafischonchol said, you should also stop and start `php artisan serve` on local after enabling gd extension on php.ini file and stop and start apache.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the gd extension?

try this is your termital

```
php -i | grep gd
```

my output is:

```
frank@frank-ThinkPad-T430:~$ php -i | grep gd
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After all the above failed, I upgraded to php 7.3.x from php7.2.x, using

```
    sudo apt install php
```

then installed gd

```
    sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

to be sure, restart the apache server or xampp(as was for my case) and also restart php artisan serve.

Using the appropriate php.ini file, ensure that "extension=php_gd2.dll" is enabled by removing the semicolon that appears before it.

then check what you have on grep through

```
    php -i | grep -i --color gd
```

it should look like this.

```
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.5
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
GDM_LANG => C.UTF-8
GDMSESSION => gnome
XAUTHORITY => /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
$_SERVER['GDM_LANG'] => C.UTF-8
$_SERVER['GDMSESSION'] => gnome
$_SERVER['XAUTHORITY'] => /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
```

in the case that after this, you get an error concerning drivers on your laravel app, this answer may help solve it.[Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

I hope this helps you.