# Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, sqlite

I am developing a website on a server I only have access to MySQL and FTP, so all commands I run are through the b374k php shell . I am experiencing a Laravel problem with SQL driver. I tried switching to file-hosted SQLite (in database/database.sqlite), but the thrown exception is the same as when using MySQL. The input & output of the console is as follows:

```
   php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
    [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table ' and name = migrations)
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
could not find driver
 [PDOException]
could not find driver
```

The Apache extensions installed on the server are:

```
    /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/15-xml.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-dom.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, 
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

What can be the problem and how can I fix it? (I don't have access to root bash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: With anything like this the first thing to do is make sure you're using artisan on the right server, i.e. it is the version connected to the database (and not the local copy that isn't).

Comment: This happened to me when I upgraded to PHP 7.3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297109/470749 fixed it: `apt-get install php7.3-mysql`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You might need to uncomment the following in your php.ini file.

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Taken from this post:
[Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)
.  I think I had to do something exactly like this when setting up laravel on digital ocean.

Comment: I had mariadb in  archlinux, un-commented `;extension=pdo_mysql` which worked

Comment: in my case i'm using PostgreSQL. After activating the "pdo_pgsql" extension and restarting the server the problem was gone.

Comment: In my case I needed to uncomment ;extension=pdo_mysql.so

Comment: Solved my problem by uncommenting  this line `extension=pdo_mysql` from php.ini. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I get "cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory /usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_mysql.so" after uncommenting `;extension=pdo_mysql.so` on a fresh php8.0

Answer (score 87):

Your database driver is missing. To solve the probelm

First install the driver

For ubuntu: For mysql database.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql/php7.2-mysql
```

You also can search for other database systems.

You also can search for the driver:

```
sudo apt-cache search drivername
```

Then Run the cmd `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Thanks I used `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql` in accordance to my PHP version.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysql after php8 installed

Answer (score 59):

I got the same error when running my test suite. It was working before but it stopped working after I upgraded php. So I did

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 58):

Even simpler in Ubuntu (18.04)

`apt install php-mysql`

Done. No need to edit any `.ini` files.

Comment: This is the fix if you recently upgraded PHP but don't have the current (or correspondent to your PHP version) edition of the php-mysql driver. In my case, I recently updated to PHP 7.2, so had to run: apt install php-mysql

Comment: for php7.2 run `apt install php7.2-mysql`. And you have edit `;` in php.ini file too for the line `extension=pdo_mysql`

Comment: Future me, remember to run sudo, as in "sudo apt install php-mysql"

Answer (score 16):

First check `php -m`

.If you don't see mysql driver install mysql `sudo apt-cache search php-mysql`

Your results will be similar to:

```
php-mysql - MySQL module for PHP [default]
```

install php- mysql Driver

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql
```

Answer (score 16):

**Solution 1:**

```
1. php -v
```

**Output:** PHP 7.3.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)

```
2. sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql
```

**Solution 2:**

Check your DB credentials like **DB Name**, **DB User**, **DB Password**

Comment: Yes, it works. And you cand find Laravel PHP version when your develop server suns via `php artisan serve`. It will be like: Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Sun Feb 23 14:52:16 2020] **PHP 7.4.3** Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started

Answer (score 12):

**ERROR:
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `tests` where `slug` = a limit 1)**

I was getting the above error in my laravel project, i am using nginx server on ubuntu 16.04

This error is because, `php-mysql` driver is missing. To install it type following command.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Please specify your current `php version` in above command.

Open `php.ini` file and uncomment the followling line of code(Remove Semicolon).

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
```

Then Restart the nginx and php service

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably missing sqlite or the specific DB driver you are trying to migrate.

Install the DB driver and you'd be fine. You don't necessarily need to edit your php.ini file (it's one way to fix it too though).

For sqlite do --> `sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`
Then `php artisan migrate`

NB: I assume you have PHP and MySql already installed

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable these extensions in the php.ini file

Before:

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=mysqli
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=sqlite3
```

After:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

It is advisable that you also activate the fileinfo extension, many packages require this.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue in Ubuntu 16.04 and what help me was that i installed php-mysql for php 7.2. I would recommend you run the following command if you have php 7.2 or install php mysql depending on your version of PHP. Make sure that you have installed the DBAL packege

```
apt-get install php7.2-mysql

systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and I uncomment `extension=pdo_sqlite` and ran the `migration` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem while using sqlite 3:

1. Make sure the changes made on .env.example and the same on the .env file.
2. Then run `$` sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3 on terminal.
3. Finally `$` php artisan migrate.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sqlite-database-throw-error-could-not-find-driver-sql-pragma-foreign-keys-on

Answer (score 5):

In Linux Download Mysql and Php

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

Then the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 5):

Create a .env file.

if using laravel and composer, generate a key for project.

php artisan key:generate

Answer (score 3):

Not really answer to original question but might help to someone:

When using docker you have to execute:

```
docker-compose exec [NAME_OF_DOCKER_SERVICE] php artisan migrate
```

Instead of only `php artisan migrate`

Just wanted to share this as I have made this error few times already

Answer (score 2):

Finally I fixed this. There was a typo in the server configuration and all paths to php extecutables were fine except the path to php-cli, which caused the error. When I fixed the path, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS7，I try this: `yum install php-mysql`, then edit php.ini

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed new version of php 7.2+ then you have to uncomment this line in php.ini 
;extension=pdo_mysql

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm using Ubuntu so I found that my system is not installed php-sqlite3,  after installation its got fixed.

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3`

Comment: Yep this is the most common solution for most of the cases and it's explained in this article.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-migrate-gives-me-an-error-could-not-find-driver

Answer (score 2):

In case that you run test in sqlite run

```
sudo apt install sqlite3 && sudo apt install php-sqlite3
```

If you run test in window, you dont need install nothing. Only config your `phpunit.xml`

Answer (score 2):

For me, these steps worked in Ubuntu with PHP 7.3:

```
1. vi /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini > uncomment:
  ;extension=pdo_sqlite
  ;extension=pdo_mysql
2. sudo apt-get install php7.3-sqlite3
3. sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

For sqlite on debian/ubuntu

PHP 7.1

```
sudo apt install php7.1-sqlite3
```

PHP 7.2

```
sudo apt install php7.2-sqlite3
```

PHP 7.3

```
sudo apt install php7.3-sqlite3
```

PHP 7.4

```
sudo apt install php7.4-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2):

for Windows 8.1/10 in :\php.ini file you should uncomment line "extension=pdo_mysql"

Answer (score 2):

For php 8 running on laravel 8 (ubuntu), run `sudo apt install php8.0.3-mysql` then restart apache
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

In window OS. I have uncomment extension=pdo_mysql for php.ini file that locate at same directory of php.exe. after that it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Some Additional information for people who upgraded their php version.

This is for **laravel framework** using **MySql** or **MariaDB**.

I had issues after upgrading php version from 7.2 to 7.4.

1. Make sure you completely install php extentions and packages for php version 7.4 (Or your installed php version).
2. Make sure you enable these extentions. pdo_mysql, xmlrpc, mbstring, mysqli, openssl, fileinfo, gd2, curl at php.ini.
3. Then clear cache, config
4. Restart all services such as apache, supervisor

Answer (score 1):

For me, `php.ini` was OK, but I needed to **restart** `php artisan serve`.

Answer (score 1):

in ubuntu or windows

- path php.ini
- php -i [image]
- Remove the **;** from **;extension=pdo_mysql** or
  **extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll** and add **extension=pdo_mysql.so**

  restart **xampp** or **wampp**
- **install sudo apt-get install php-mysql**

and

php artisan migrate

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, I followed the same path as the previous answers. The difference is that the path to php.ini is usually different from the traditional ones, usually in Apache.

To find php.ini, I used the following path: `C:\tools\php80\php.ini`

After that, I uncommented the `pdo extension files` and the migration worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I the php path was different from xampp php path that my project hosted on.

So I just change the system path from the pure php path to the php path in xamppp and all working fine.

I run this command in Ubuntu

`sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php`

may you have installed the php so like me you need to first run this command and then try above again

`sudo rm /usr/bin/php`

May your composer has some issue so you need to run this as well

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer`

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/563993

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me using `sail` for development. In this case the solution was to run the command inside the container

```
docker exec -it <app-container-id> php artisan migrate
```

The app container id is probably like this:

```
<app-name>_laravel.test_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `pdo_mysql` extension is enabled on your cPanel