# Artisan migrate could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install Laravel. I have installed `Xampp`, but when I try to setup my database using `php artisan migrate`I get the error:

> **[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead
>   and table_name =    migrations)   [PDOException]   could not find
>   driver**

`config/database.php` file has the relevant connections:

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],
```

Any ideas?

Comment: On your `database.php` Does the `default connection name` was set to this? `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`?

Comment: Have you created database set in your `.env`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

In your php.ini configuration file simply uncomment the extension:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

*(You can find your **php.ini** file in the php folder where your stack server is installed.)*

If you're on **Windows** make it: `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

If you're on **Linux** make it: `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

And do a quick server restart.

*If this isn't working for you, you may need to install **pdo_mysql** extension into your php library.*

Comment: it can also be the whole php-mysql extension missing. so maybe also something like: sudo apt install php7.3-mysql (change 7.3 whit your php ver)

Comment: @Krishna Kant Chourasiya , hello i am also getting error in migration please help me , i have tried all the solution given in this page nothing working . here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716326/php-laravel-artisan-migrate-error-in-model

Comment: The error is the same for all SQL drivers, so for who are not using MySQL try install your SQL driver... like php-pgsql or php-sqlite3.

Comment: for php version 8.2.5 its:
`extension=pdo_mysql`
just search for `pdo_mysql` in your php.ini file instead of `php_pdo_mysql`, and then uncomment.

Answer (score 61):

We have solved the same error by following the below steps.

linux command for this type of error occurred then, first of all, check your php.ini file

```
If your php.ini file exists then in configuration file simply uncomment the extension:

;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll 

Else follow below steps

step1:php -v

step2: Install php mysql extension

php 7.0 sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql

php 7.1 sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql

php 7.2 sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql

php 7.3 sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql

step3: service apache2 restart

step4: php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 49):

if you've installed `php` and `mysql` in your linux machine, php needs `php-mysql` extention to communicate with mysql. so make sure you've also installed this extention using:

`sudo yum install php-mysql` in redhat based machines.

and

`sudo apt-get install php-mysql` in debian machines.

Comment: This answer worked for me in ubuntu 18.04 thanks @Ali_Hr

Comment: This answer worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, i was using Xampp as my localhost environment thanks for saving my day @Ali_Hr

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 32):

You also need to install the PHP-MySQL drivers:

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that you've installed **php-mysql**, the pdo needs php-mysql to operate properly. If not you could simply type

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

Answer (score 14):

the same problem I got but after I run this line of code.

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

Done.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a little late, nevertheless i'm answering this for anyone still experiencing this issue on windows (USING XAMPP).

Step 1. Verify that there is a mismatch in your PHP version.
        To do this, open routes/web.php and create a simple route to return the php information like so:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
   return response()->json([
    'stuff' => phpinfo()
   ]);
})
```

[image: phpinfo]

```
and compare this with output from your command line
```

[image]

```
As we can see, in my case there is a mismatch, this usually happens if you have multiple versions of php installed.
```

Step 2. Add the php version being used by your xampp to your system path
[image]

Step 3. Verify that you have the extension enabled in your php.ini file. 
NB. Make sure you are editing the php.ini file that is shown under the 'loaded configuration file' entry in the results of phpinfo() command.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

In your `php.ini` configuration file simply uncomment the extension:

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
```

(You can find your php.ini file in the php folder where your server is installed.)

make this to

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

now you need to configure your .env file in  find `DB_DATABASE=` write in that database name which you used than migrate like if i used my database and database name is "abc" than i need to write there `DB_DATABASE=abc` and save that .env file and run command again

```
php artisan migrate
```

so after run than you got some msg like as:

```
php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
```

Answer (score 7):

I am a Windows and XAMPP user. What works for me is adding `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in both `php.ini` of XAMPP and `php.ini` in `C:\php\php.ini`.

Run this command in your cmd to know where your config file is

`php -i | find /i "Configuration File`

Answer (score 6):

In Windows and PHP 7.4.5 go to php.ini and uncomment this line

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Answer (score 6):

This error is the same for all SQL drivers, so for who are **not** using MySQL try install **your** SQL driver...

SQL Lite:

```
sudo apt install php-sqlite3
```

PostgreSQL:

```
sudo apt install php-pgsql
```

Comment: for me, i need to install exactly the php version for it, such as php7.4-pgsql

Answer (score 4):

If you are on linux systems
please try running `sudo php artisan migrate`
As for me,sometimes database operations need to run with sudo in laravel.

Answer (score 4):

Install by running `sudo apt install php-mysql` and enabling `extension=pdo_mysql` in `php.ini`

Then reload apache by running `sudo systemctl reload apache2`

To quickly find your php.ini in your server, just run this command: `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"`

Laravel Side:

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan migrate
```

It works for me and good luck!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying to enable the extension inside a Docker image:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
```

Based on [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57183527/12015105).

Also props to [@Krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47929207/12015105) for shedding some light on the extension issue.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for me (Nginx / php**8.1** / ubuntu 20.04)

1. In php.ini uncomment Mysql PDO extension

   ```
    extension=pdo_mysql
   ```
2. Install extension

   ```
    sudo apt install php8.1-pdo-mysql
   ```
3. Restart Nginx

   ```
    sudo systemctl reload nginx
   ```

Comment: `sudo apt install php8.1-pdo-mysql` gives me `unable to locate package php8.1-pdo-mysql`

Answer (score 1):

If you are matching with sqlite database:
In your *php* folder open *php.ini* file, go to:

```
;extension=pdo_sqlite
```

Just remove the semicolon and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I am so embarrassed. I know this doesn't help those using XAMPP, but I had to share.  I have an out-of-the-box Laravel installation in Vagrant using a ScotchBox virtual machine running in Windows 10.  And I am following the Digital Ocean tutorial.  This should just work.

Like you, I ran `php artisan migrate` and I got

> `could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)`

A few hours later, I thought

> Maybe I should try inside of the Vagrant shell?

I opened `vagrant ssh` and ran `php artisan migrate` again. There I got a different message:

> `Could not open input file: artisan`

A few more hours later, I got it right.

`vagrant ssh`

`cd \var\www\`

`php artisan migrate`

> `Migration table created successfully`

So, yeah. I was in the wrong shell *and* the wrong folder.

Answer (score 1):

For php 8.2 > you will have to go into the php ini file which is located i assume in `C:\php-8.2` and you want to find `;extension=pdo_mysql` and remove the `;`.

So now you will have inside the php ini file `extension=pdo_mysql`.

After that, restart the server and you will go to go.

Some of the above answers.. are old and they are using `php7` etc.. That's why they are telling you to find in the php ini file the `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` which in the newest versions of php are written like this `extension=pdo_mysql`

Answer (score 0):

whilst sometimes you might have multiple php versions, you might also have a held-back version of php-mysql.. do a sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql | grep php and compare what you get from php -v

Answer (score 0):

Go to .env file and change the following

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=shreemad
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Change the DB_PASSWORD field to

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=shreemad
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=" "
```

In my case it works

### NOTE: If your password in mysql is null

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu or windows

- Remove the ; from ;extension=pdo_mysql or extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
  and add extension=pdo_mysql.so

  restart xampp or wampp
- install sudo apt-get install php-mysql

and

php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple php versions installed applied all other options like UN commenting driver in php.ini and it does not work you might missed following step

1. Please check `php -v` from cmd
2. Go to your environment variables by right clicking on PC and properties
3. Check path of your php key, it might be pointing to older version.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Windows Users. Make the below changes for both php.ini files in C:/xampp and the file in Program Files, which was created while installing PHP.

Uncomment the below line (by removing the ; sign before the line)

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

And add the below line, if not present.

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the methods above, try this:

Check the PHP used by the terminal by typing `php -v`,
then try to check the PHP used by your XAMPP by entering the XAMPP shell then typing `php -v`.

If there is a difference, then edit the PHP path in the system environment variable, and navigate to the PHP file used by XAMPP,  Usually "c:\xampp\php".

Try to check if the PHP Terminal version with PHP XAMPP is the same, if so, then your problem should be solved