# could not find driver error when using php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel-5

I started a new blog project to try Laravel. I followed the tutorial from https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/1?autoplay=true .I changed .env file

```
DB_DATABASE=homestead 
DB_USERNAME=homestead 
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

to

```
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Then type

`php artisan migrate`

and get an error

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)

  at /home/morilon/php_proj/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      /home/morilon/php_proj/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=blog", "root", "", [])
      /home/morilon/php_proj/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

What does that mean `could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations) ?` 
After installing PHP i reinstalled MySQL with that commands:

```
pkg --get-selections | grep mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge [everything that came up]
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

--Update--

After

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.2-curl php7.2-dev php7.2-gd php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml
```

error changes

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)
```

Comment: For anyone still having similar issues check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver/52717055#52717055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last error was because I didn't enter password for MySQL user in files `config/database.php and .env.`

Answer (score 9):

You also need to install the PHP-MySQL drivers:

`sudo apt install php-mysql`

Comment: Ok, i installed PHP-MySQL drivers with 'sudo apt install php-mysql'.

Comment: But there is the same error. What else that may be?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem with SQLite database.

I had to install php-sqlite3 for it to work.

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

Then execute your migrate command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Hope this helps anyone using sqlite.