# PHP Laravel could not migrate files to database

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to connect with PHP and MySQL through the database using Laravel doing:

`php artisan migrate` but I'm experiencing a common error:

> "Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver"

(I'm using XAMPP to start up the server if that makes a difference)

The values I changed in database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3308'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test2'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

I also changed the .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=test2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

The things I did were:

- See if the `extension=pdo_mysql` is uncommented which it was.
- Typed in `php artisan migrate:refresh`
- Restarted Xampp
- Deleted and recreated the migration file. Also incremented the last digit of the number (taken advice from one of the answers)
- Check the version (which is the latest)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artisan migrate could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Please check in this link. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 1):

composer update

composer require doctrine/dbal

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if pro_mysql is activated on your install.

You can do this by creating a file and adding the following:

```
phpinfo();
```

Then navigate to it in your browser. If it is activated you will see it in the list.

Here is some more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Hope that helps.