# Having issues using migrations in Laravel due to driver errors for SQL

Tags: laravel

When I migrate my tables using the `php artisan migrate` command I get the following error :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from i nformation_schema.tables where table_schema = test and
>   table_name = migrations and t able_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Sorry if this is an easy fix but I'm really new to using Laravel so this has me scratching my head and I don't really understand what is causing the error

Comment: Just copy / paste your error in Google, you will find answers, for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artisan migrate could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: All the solutions point to editing a file called php.ini which I don't have in my directory so I'm lost here

Answer (score 0):

What driver are you using for your database?

(I'm assuming you're on linux or mac and are running your migrations from your host machine and not while SSH'd into your Vagrant Box or similar)

If it's MySQL:

Find PHP config file:

`$ php -i | grep -Ei php.ini`

Output:

```sh
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/php.ini
```

`$ sudo nano /etc/php/php.ini`

Then press ctrl+W to search, type `mysql` and hit enter.

You should see the extensions list, in there remove the `;` infront of `extension=pdo_mysql`

Now run `$ php -v`

And if you see something along the lines of "Extension pdo_mysql.so not found". (You may need `pdo_pgsql` or `pdo_sqlite3`, depending on the driver you're running)

You just need to install the correct version of `php-mysql` for your PHP installation.

Your `$ php -v` output should show the version of PHP you're running.

Once the output of `$ php -v` shows no errors, you should be good to go.

Comment: When I search for mysql in the php.ini file I get "mysql"  not found which doesn't make sense to me because I know I have mysql installed on this machine. Thanks for your patience btw

Comment: Try scrolling through the file to find the list of lines that start `;extension=...`

Add `extension=pdo_mysql` to the end of the list.