# How to enable php's mysql extensions in docker container?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i have the following docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: nginx:1.17.1-alpine
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  links:
    - php

php:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
  links:
    - mysql

mysql:
  image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:latest
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
environment: 
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

and following dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.0-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

In this setup , php's mysql extensions or docker mysql extensions never get installed.  i cannot access mysql from php container.  adminer.php complains saying "None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are available."

How do we fix this problem ?

Answer (score 64):

Adding the following to dockerfile fixed the issue.

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
```

Comment: in the original post , its bit different, pdo parts are missing in it.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think the `mysqli` bit is not really required. It's an extension apart from PDO.