# php artisan migrate error in manjaro linux

Tags: laravel, manjaro

Im using laravel in manjaro linux.. if I excute php artisan migrate command it gives me this erro how I fix this. also Im already install xampp
thank you..

error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from     information_schema.tables where table_schema = nws and table_name = migrations and t    able_type = 'BASE TABLE')

at /run/media/snake/Entertainment/VS/linuxTest/Nurses/NW/vendor/laravel/framework/src/  Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
 663|         catch (Exception $e) {
> 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|
Exception trace:

    1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
    run/media/snake/Entertainment/VS/linuxTest/Nurses/NW/vendor/laravel/framework/src/
    lluminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

      2 PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=nws", "root", "", [])
    /run/media/snake/Entertainment/VS/linuxTest/Nurses/NW/vendor/laravel/framework/src/
    Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

    Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: please show your DB part in .env

Comment: Do you have drivers installed?

Comment: take a look at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artisan migrate could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: @AmalSR 
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=nws
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Have you created the database set in your .env?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ yes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed Maria / MySQL and it's PHP driver.

```
sudo pacman -Syu mariadb mariadb-clients libmariadbclient
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is use localhost instead 127.0.0.1 in .env...

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

try this, worked for me...