# I got error while migrating laravel migrations in arch linux

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-migrations, arch

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }

      +29 vendor frames 

  30  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I searched it from google and i got [question like mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753139/php-artisan-migrate-error-in-manjaro-linux) but that solution didn't work

Comment: Seriously, how can you expect help with this kind of message, please, re-write your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry for mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have the mysql driver extension configured for php?

Check your php.ini

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Remove the `;` from the beginning if there is one, save, and then reload php.

More details:

[Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)