# Laravel Exception could not find driver SQ limit 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, driver, limit

i was learning laravel6 from scratch from laracast.com and when i started to use the database. I bumped into the following problem:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL: select
>   * from `posts` where `slug` = my-first-post limit 1)

I use wamp with phpmyadmin. I tried xamp and mySQL workbench. I updated my dependencies, but without result.

this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $post = \DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if(! $post){
            abort(404);
        }

     return view('post', [
         'post' => $post
     ]);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please help me with this problem?

Best regards,
Jeff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Artisan migrate could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i installed composer. I needed to assign the location of my php.exe. This field was empty so i installed php when i already had wampp installed.

Solution:
I uninstalled wampp, composer and deleted php. I started over and installed xampp first. When i wanted to install composer. It immediately suggested php.exe in my xampp folder. After installing laravel the problem was solved.

Conclusion:
Composer installation went wrong. Since i had multiple php's in my system i probably assignt composer to the wrong one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you insert \DB in namespace

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class PostsController extends Controller
{
   public function show($slug)
    {
        $post = \DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if(! $post){
            abort(404);
        }


     return view('post', [
         'post' => $post
     ]);
    }
}
```