# Why can't I view this laravel project?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am admittedly new to Laravel and back end development but I'm trying to open a Laravel project in my browser and am receiving an error message instead. I'm inheriting this project from a client who was working with another group of developers and they have since gone AWOL so I'm on my own to try to figure out what the issue is here.

The first error messages were:

```
**Warning:** require(C:\xampp\htdocs\vizzue\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\vizzue\bootstrap\autoload.php** on line **17**

**Fatal error:** require():Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vizzue\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in **C:\xampp\htdocs\vizzue\bootstrap\autoload.php** on line **17**
```

To try to fix that error (from a solution I found on here), I ran `composer install` in the terminal to try to download the missing files. That switched the previous error messages to `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` (Not very helpful).

So then I found more advice on here to get more detailed errors for my problem and was outputted a long list of errors under four separate headings.

Heading 1

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = hA02gV6ShpNslkw0N8Wrgm8QmyA0ZxoXfCNHsVTK limit 1)
```

Heading 2

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Heading 3

```
QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = hA02gV6ShpNslkw0N8Wrgm8QmyA0ZxoXfCNHsVTK limit 1)
```

Heading 4

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My PHP version is: PHP 7.2.28

My Laravel version is: Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Also, I have created a `.env` by copying the `.env-example` file.

**EDIT:**

I found the database information inside of the `database/migrations` directory so I actually DO have the database files. I'm still having an error, however. I ran `php artisan generate:key` and that was fine. But when I ran `php artisan migrate` I got the following error:

```
In Connection.php line 647:

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where ta   
  ble_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)


In Connector.php line 68:

  could not find driver
```

Comment: You have wrong database credentials. Check your .env file!

Comment: I should've mentioned that in the question but I already copied the .env-example to a .env file. The database properties were already set in the project that I received but I don't have a database that was sent over in the batch of laravel files. Is that what's causing the issue?

Comment: Can you post your `config/database.php` ? I'm assuming you've [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#configuration) about configuring your database?

Comment: If you run the `mysql --version` in the terminal / console, what version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your `.env` file to enable laravel access on your database. If you don't have one just copy the `.env.example` file and rename it to `.env`.

And then change the following properties:

DB_DATABASE=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME

DB_USERNAME=USER_NAME

DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD

and then you should run `php artisan key:generate` to generate a new encryption key

**EDIT**

For your new problem you should run `composer update` and then `composer require doctrine/dbal`

if that does not work

You might need to comment out the following in your php.ini file.

`;extension=pdo_mysql.so`

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: I should've mentioned that in the question but I already copied the .env-example to a .env file. The database properties were already set in the project that I received but I don't have a database that was sent over in the batch of laravel files. Is that what's causing the issue? And I've run the `php artisan key:generate` command and still no luck.

Comment: you already ran the `php artisan migrate` to create all the tables for your database?

Comment: `php artisan migrate` gives me a whole other set of issues. But I don't have a database that was sent over with the rest of the project (I inherited the project from another group of developers who I can't communicate with).

Comment: i understand but you should create a new dabatase with the right name and then run the migrations, and try this again and see if you can pass this first issue. This error is occuring because there is something wrong with the properties you set. Make sure  DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD are correct

Comment: I gotcha Lucas! I just created a database via phpmyadmin and updated the properties in `.env`. Please see the updated question!

Comment: in this case you should take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver let me know if it works. This problem is very common in new projects

Comment: My php.ini file doesn't have the `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` extension to edit. I added `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` to the bottom of the list of extensions but still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: you ran the `composer update` and `composer require doctrine/dbal` commands? i edited my answer

Comment: I just ran both commands. Each gave me some yellow highlighted warnings and I still can't load the home page of this project :-(

Comment: Yes, I'm completely lost as to why this isn't opening for me

Comment: Ok, try restarting your apache serve and run the php artisan migrate again. I think your mysql or php is missing some dependecies here

Comment: Restarted and ran `php artisan migrate` and got these errors: In Connection.php line 647:
                                                                                 
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where ta  
  ble_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)                            
                                                                                 

In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  could not find driver

Comment: The error has changed a bit, you configured your config/database.php file with your credentials?

Comment: Yes sir. I updated the credentials in the `.env` file but it's still checking for the previous credentials

Answer (score 1):

first you have change the name of .env.example to .env then configure your database names settings in it. after that run composer install to install your project dependencies. make sure your webserver is up and running

Comment: I should've mentioned that in the question but I already copied the .env-example to a .env file. The database properties were already set in the project that I received but I don't have a database that was sent over in the batch of laravel files. Is that what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic installation process for a laravel project. I'll try to explain each of them so that you'll be able to figure out your mistakes on your own.

- Getting the source code

You first need to get the source code of your app . Most of the time it's done via git . For instance , you'll need to type `git clone https://github.com/miracuthbert/saas-boilerplate.git yoursaasproject` to clone the repository hosted on github [here](https://github.com/miracuthbert/saas-boilerplate)

- Install dependencies

  Go to the root of the directory of the source code you previously got by typing
  `cd projectname`.
  The laravel framework uses composer as its dependencies manager. So you need to install it . (What you already did)
  Then, from the root of your project, type the following intructions in the same order :

  `composer install`

  `composer update`
- Environment configuration

The environment variables of the laravel framework are managed through a dot env file. An example file named .env.example is generally provided. You'll find it at the root of your project's folder. Assuming you are using a terminal with a bash prompt, type the following command to copy the .env.example to a .env file :

`cp .env.example .env`

After getting your new .env file, type

`php artisan key:generate`

to generate secure key in your .env file

Depending on the type of database management system you intend to use, here are some specific configurations to add in your .env file :

- MySQL

If you choose MySQL as your DBMS, set the following values in your .env file :

```
     DB_CONNECTION


     DB_DATABASE


     DB_USERNAME  


     DB_PASSWORD
```

homestead is the default DB_USERNAME and localhost is the default database host. Localhost is totally fine for working locally but you need to change your DB_USERNAME to an actual user of your DBMS with the corresponding password.

- Sqlite

If you use sqlite, create a new sqlite database by typing :

```
`touch database/database.sqlite`
```

After setting up your database, enter the following command to create and populate tables :
`php artisan migrate --seed`

You may also need to edit other variables in the .env. The official laravel documentation is your best companion for that.
This is to the best of my knowledge what you need to do.

As for the driver error, here are few potential solutions adapted from an answer to a similar problem question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql) :

Be sure to configure the 'default' key in app/config/database.php

For mysql, this would be 'default' => 'mysql',

If you are receiving a [PDOException] could not find driver error, check to see if you have the correct PHP extensions installed. You need pdo_mysql.so and mysql.so installed and enabled. Instructions on how to do this vary between operating systems.

For Windows, the mysql extensions should come pre-downloaded with the official PHP distribution. Just edit your php.ini and uncomment the lines extension=pdo_mysql.so and extension=mysql.so

Also, in php.ini, make sure extension_dir is set to the proper directory. It should be a folder called extensions or ext or similar inside your PHP install directory.

There are other instructions given in the original answer but I'm only recommending those I understand. It was initially written for a postgres dbms.

If there are still problems, take a look at [laragon](https://laragon.org/). It's a bit like xamp (that you appear to be using on windows OS), but more powerful and easier to use.
The main backend languages and frameworks can be set up easily in few minutes. That includes php with laravel/symfony, ruby and Ruby on Rails, python and Django.
It allows you to manage multiple versions of the same programming language without any hassle and is fully extendable.
If you're new to Laravel or backend development, and working on the windows operating system, this is a must have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm still running into the `could not find driver` error