# Laravel migrations is not connecting AWS-RDS postgres (could not find driver ...). PDO already installed. How to solve that?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, amazon-ec2, migration, amazon-rds

I am using an Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance with php7.4/NGINX and Laravel 8.4 point to a PostgreSQL RDS instance (no public access) in AWS.

When I try to migrate (`php artisan migrate`) I am getting the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = xxxxx-db-prod and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver) in SO is point in how to install or enable the PostgreSQL drive. But I have already it installed and enabled.
Running `php -i` this is what I get:

```
pdo_pgsql

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4)

pgsql

PostgreSQL Support => enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4)
PostgreSQL(libpq)  => PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
Multibyte character support => enabled
SSL support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent => On => On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent => Off => Off
pgsql.ignore_notice => Off => Off
pgsql.log_notice => Off => Off
pgsql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
```

Running `php -m` this is what I get:

```
...

pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
Phar
...
```

I have tested the same instance point to a local PostgreSQL instance, inside the same Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance and it works. It seems that this is not a Laravel issue. Seems to be something related to the RDS-PostgreSQL connection.

Does someone have any clue related to this issue?

Update

---

I notice that the origin of the issue was the `DB_CONNECTION` value. I forgot to change `mysql` to `pgsql` in the `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
```

Comment: Did you restart your php and nginx ?

Comment: yes I just did and I still face the issue.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I forgot to change DB_CONNECTION=mysql to pgsql. Now I have another issue - timeout expired .... It is another issue but at least this one is solved.

Comment: Can you share your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, after restarting the ec2 instance everything worked.

¯_(ツ)_/¯