# PDOException in my Laravel application, despite having pdo_mysql installed

Tags: php, laravel, dbal

I am trying to run a new Laravel app on my sever but I am getting the following error:

> QueryException (SQL) could not find driver (SQL: select * from
>   `settings` limit 1)

Using the debugbar I can see the error is for PDO: LOG.error:

> PDOException: could not find driver in
>   /home/mysite.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:

What doesn't make sense is that I actually already have PDO installed, I know this because I ran the first `php artisan migrate` and it created all the tables in my MYSQL DB fine.

I have ran `php -m | grep mysql` to verify what mysql related PHP extensions I have:

```
$ php -m | grep mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
```

I should note that PHP *can* use MySQL as I have a Wordpress blog running on the same server fine.

I have already tried clearing the cache and updating composer packages, I have also completely removed `doctrine/dbal` and reinstalled.

**Update:** If I remove the package `doctrine/dbal` and clear the caches, I still receive an error about PDOExceptions:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver
>   /home/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#68

Comment: did you installed mysql driver?

Comment: Yeah its installed as it has successfully ran the migrations, its just the site which shows this page when I try to load it.

Comment: its a configuration issue, there isn't just 1 php configuration ... the cli configuration sounds good, but the other configuration is missing a driver

Comment: Can you elaborate what configuration is missing?

Comment: stupid question, where did you use the doctrine/dbal? is it _mandatory_? if you used plain laravel, i believe you won't need it. and start blame the doctrine/dbal first instead of laravel if migration works.

Comment: @BagusTesa I think this package is required if you rename columns/table names.

Comment: could you be more specific on *rename columns/table names*?

Comment: @BagusTesa It allows you to rename columns\tables in migrations, without this you cannot complete this task on certain DB systems (i.e. mysql)

Comment: could you post on how you use this database abstraction layer? i noticed it had [several adapters](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver) for different drivers.. and noticed there is no mysqlnd.. the repo did not show on how to use the code, so i could not help much.. this issue is not laravel bound, you should tag it with dbal to draw attention of dbal users.

Comment: @BagusTesa Please see updated question, I don't think this is actually related to `dbal`.

Comment: whoops my bad, it seems indeed `dbal` used by [`laravel/framework` under the hood](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#L7). could you put back the dbal? also, may we know the database configuration, especially the driver? (it might be stored in either `database.php` or `.env`). also, could you specify the laravel version? also, [a discussion may suggest it is possible to be caused by environment issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6427). is the apache stack is installed manually? (i mean, without LAMPP or equivalent).

Comment: can you check and share if the databse config is the same in cli and web as @BagusTesa said? you can do so with `php artisan tinker` (or in any console command) and in any route callback or controller with `dd(config('database'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
composer update

composer require doctrine/dbal
```

It looks like you have a missing dependency

Notice:

You might need to comment out the following in your php.ini file.

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

[stackoverflow.com/a/42561002/2109233 source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42561002/2109233)

Comment: Did you also restart the web server (Apache/Nginx)?

Comment: Also are you sure that you have DB_CONNECTION= 'mysql' in your .env file?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned `php artisan migrate` works, I believe this also uses the `.env` settings