# php artisan migrate error could not find driver

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

I'm running into a `Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver` error when trying to run `php artisan migrate`.

I looked around but couldn't find a solution to this exception.

I am running Laravel 5.6 with PHP 7.2 and MySQL 5.7 on a windows computer.

Here is the .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=larabiz
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

And there is the detailed error log:

```
php artisan migrate -v

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = larabiz and table_name = migrations)

  at C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php: 664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php : 47

  2   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php : 43

  3   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=larabiz", "root", "root", [])
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php : 43

  4   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=larabiz", "root", "root", [])
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 65

  5   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createPdoConnection("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=larabiz", "root", "root", [])
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 44

  6   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createConnection("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=larabiz", [])
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php : 24

  7   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector::connect()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php : 183

  8   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 915

  9   call_user_func(Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 915

  10  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdo()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 940

  11  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getReadPdo()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 399

  12  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdoForSelect()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 325

  13  Illuminate\Database\Connection::Illuminate\Database\{closure}("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?")
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 657

  14  Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?", Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 624

  15  Illuminate\Database\Connection::run("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?", Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 333

  16  Illuminate\Database\Connection::select("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?")
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php : 18

  17  Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::hasTable("migrations")
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository.php : 169

  18  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository::repositoryExists()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php : 545

  19  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::repositoryExists()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand.php : 97

  20  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::prepareDatabase()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand.php : 63

  21  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::handle()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 29

  22  call_user_func_array([])
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 29

  23  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 87

  24  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 31

  25  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php : 564

  26  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php : 183

  27  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php : 252

  28  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php : 170

  29  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php : 865

  30  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php : 241

  31  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php : 143

  32  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php : 88

  33  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php : 121

  34  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\Cyril\Projects\larabiz\artisan : 37
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: I second that @Alex

Comment: Where are you running the command from?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Ubuntu 16.04 and what help me was that i installed php-mysql for php 7.2. I would recommend you run the following command if you have php 7.2 or install php mysql depending on your version of PHP

```
apt-get install php7.2-mysql

systemctl restart apache2
```