# I'm trying to run the php artisan migrate command, but I'm not getting it. I'm getting this error

Tags: php, laravel

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = sisfosekolah and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: please check your all migration file in database and also migration folder.

Comment: i already check and only 2 file migration

Comment: the error :
660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**In your php.ini configuration file simply uncomment the extension:**



  ;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

(You can find your php.ini file in the php folder where your stack server is installed.)

If you're on Windows make it: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

If you're on Linux make it: extension=pdo_mysql.so

And do a quick server restart.
```

Comment: i already uncomment the extension ;extension=pdo_mysql
i am using wamp server