# Problem with php artisan migrate- laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, mamp

I'm trying to do php artisan migrate and I got this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

```
catch (Exception $e) {
664|             throw new QueryException(
665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
666|             );
667|         }
```

I have in the phpinfo `pdo_mysql` and `pdo_pgsql` and I'm using MAMP on windows.

Are there any ideas why I still get this error?

Comment: yes and didn't work

Comment: Searching for your error turns up many duplicates, have you checked them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: to be specific, update you question with your related code, in this please add .env file or config/database.php

Answer (score 0):

Am sorry for being late, please run this command `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql`
Don't forget to change `php7.4-mysql` with corresponding version of yours installed php