# could not find driver Debian SQL Server PHP

Tags: php, laravel, debian, odbc, sqlsrv

I have a Laravel installation running on a Debian 9.9 server and PHP 7.4.

I need to connect to a SQL Server database on a remote Windows server.

I followed this guide to install the PHP extensions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-the-drivers-on-debian-8-9-and-10

And this one to install the ODBC drivers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I also tried reinstalling PHP.

But even after doing all this, I still can't connect to the database and get this error:

> could not find driver `(SQL: select * from [table] where [column] = 123)`

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is are the lines where PDO is mentioned in the result of phpinfo()

```
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlsrv

pdo_sqlsrv

pdo_sqlsrv support => enabled
ExtensionVer => 5.8.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize => 10240 => 10240
sqlsrv.LogSeverity => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.SetLocaleInfo => 2 => 2
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors => On => On
```

php --ini shows that these two extensions are enabled: 
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini, 
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini

PDO::getAvailableDrivers() returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlsrv
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the Apache configuration.
Even after reinstalling it, for some reason I had still an old configuration loaded.
I had installed the driver on 7.4 and apache was still serving 7.3.

I solved it by doing:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.3
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

### Debian 9/10

Install Sury APT repository

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sury-php.list
wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
```

Install your desired php version

```
sudo apt install php7.2  php7.4  php8.0
```

Install additional desired modules (change x.x with version)

```
sudo apt install phpx.x-{mysql,cli,common,imap,ldap,xml,fpm,curl,mbstring,zip}
```

For php 7.2:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.2

sudo apt install php7.2-dev

sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set ext_dir /usr/lib/php/20170718/

sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.2 install sqlsrv
sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.2 install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -s fpm -v 7.2 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -s apache2 -v 7.2 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -s cli -v 7.2 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For php 7.4:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.4

sudo apt install php7.4-dev

sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set ext_dir /usr/lib/php/20190902

sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.4 install sqlsrv
sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.4 install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -s fpm -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -s apache2 -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -s cli -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For php 8.0:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar8.0
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.0
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize8.0
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config8.0

sudo apt install php8.0-dev

sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set ext_dir /usr/lib/php/20200930

sudo pecl -d php_sufix=8.0 install sqlsrv
sudo pecl -d php_sufix=8.0 install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -s fpm -v 8.0 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -s apache2 -v 8.0 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -s cli -v 8.0 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

sudo service php8.0-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Check loaded modules

```
php -m
```

Or just check sqlsrv

```
php -m | grep sqlsrv
```

Common trouble:

pecl extension fails because already installed

Just uninstall it:

```
sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.2 uninstall sqlsrv
sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.2 uninstall pdo_sqlsrv

sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.4 uninstall sqlsrv
sudo pecl -d php_sufix=7.4 uninstall pdo_sqlsrv

sudo pecl -d php_sufix=8.0 uninstall sqlsrv
sudo pecl -d php_sufix=8.0 uninstall pdo_sqlsrv
```

then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following, create a php file (ex: `PDO.php`) in some directory and insert the following content into it:

```
<?php
    print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
?>
```

then run this file as follows:

```
leo@alpha:~$ php PDO.php
```

Terminal should return an array of available PDO drivers. This way you can check if PHP really has the SQL driver enabled. In my case:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => pgsql
    [2] => sqlsrv
)
```

Also check that in the Laravel directory, the `.env` file has correctly configured the connection parameters to the SQL server ...

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I wish you can solve your problem.

*** EDIT 1 ***

Please try the following:

First, create a file inside the root directory of your web server `(ex: index.php)`, and inside it, insert the following content:

```
<?php
    php_info();
?>
```

access that file through your browser, and it should return all the `php settings` that `apache` is using. Look in the `PDO` section, if you have the SQL Server driver loaded ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when running pdo.php I get **mysql** and **sqlsrv**. So the driver exists.

Comment: That is a good indication, now you only have to check that the values ​​you have in the ```.env``` file are correct

Comment: Database.php and .env _should_ be ok, the same exact configuration is working fine on macOS and on another computer running Ubuntu

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what operating system are you using when you receive that error?

Comment: The server where PHP in running on is Debian version 9.9. The database is on Windows 10 Server

Comment: did you try to restart the apache2 service? ```/etc/init.d/apache2/restart```

Comment: Yes I did, I actually reinstalled apache2 and reconfigured it. I also tried both with PHP 7.3 and 7.4

Comment: That is strange, you can visit this URL, they asked the same question, maybe you can find some clues there to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing that was mentioned in that conversation helped. I really have no clue where the problem could be

Comment: Please, see my EDIT 1

Comment: I added the result of phpinfo in the question