# Laravel 6: could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, wamp, git-bash

On web, database is connected with application. But, on command line gives following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
at C:\wamp64\www\hrmnxt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669

             // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
             // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
             // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
             catch (Exception $e) {
                 throw new QueryException(
                     $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
                 );
             }


  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\wamp64\www\hrmnxt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=hrmnxt;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "postgres", "secret", [])
      C:\wamp64\www\hrmnxt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
```

**Laravel: 6**

**Postgresql 9.6**

Answer (score 0):

I never encountered such problem but perhaps you should firts start checking if you have all the requirements (of laravel installation)
 PHP Modules activated like  (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation)
Specifically this one :

> PDO PHP Extension

This link could help you debug : [Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

If it doesn't work tell me I'll help you.