# Larval "artissan migrate:fresh" don't work

Tags: php, laravel, migration

[image: the error(screenshot)]

When i try php artisan migrate:fresh this error appears, I tried enabling extension=pdo_mysql but It didn't work
error:

> could not find driver (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: The error is related to your database configuration. Check your repository credentials to properly connect to your desired DB.

Comment: It may solve this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: Have you installed the correct `php` database driver (i.e. `sudo apt install -y php-mysql`)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install your database driver.

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

or if you run a specific version of `PHP` or change `mysql` to the database you are running

```
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
```

Comment: If it helped your problem, please accept it as an answer when you can :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.env` file.
You must have the following env vars:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_PORT={YOUR_DB_PORT}
DB_HOST={YOUR_DB_HOST}
DB_DATABASE={YOUR_DB_DATABASE}
DB_USERNAME={YOUR_DB_USERNAME}
DB_PASSWORD={YOUR_DB_PASSWORD}
```