# When I run " php artisan migrate " in my project the following error occurs, How can I solve the error?

Tags: laravel

When I  run " php artisan migrate "  in my project the following error occurs, How can I solve the error?

````
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
   
could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = tc_cse-infohub and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
    
      at F:\xammp\htdocs\github\TC_CSE-infoHub\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
        708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
        709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
        710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
        711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
      ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
        713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        714▕             );
        715▕         }
        716▕     }
    ``
      1   F:\xammp\htdocs\github\TC_CSE-infoHub\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70      PDOException::("could not find driver")
  
      2   F:\xammp\htdocs\github\TC_CSE-infoHub\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70      PDO::__construct()
    ```
````

Comment: Make sure your `db` credentials in .env file are same with in database management tool.

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: un comment  extension=php_pdo.dll and restart apache and before migration/ php artisan cache:clear/
php artisan view:clear/
php artisan route:clear/

Answer (score 0):

It could be the wrong mysql port number in your .env file. Check your .env file and make sure the port number matches the same one mysql is using, also the `SQL` passwords in your env file, because the laravel framework is rejecting the connection hence the error on your screen.

Edit: If you're using windows make sure your php / db extensions are enabled on your xampp / wampp configurations.

For example: `;extension=pdo_mysql.so //uncomment this line just remove ;`

after that please try again for `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the port number and password are correct in .env file

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using ?

Comment: and also your Os? Windows / Linux or MacOs?

Comment: laravel 8 and OS windows 10.  this line is uncomment in my file extension=pdo_mysql.so

Comment: then use `php artisan optimize` and `php artisan config:cache` and then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: same error occur after using php artisan optimize and php artisan config:cache and then php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

You should install PDO on your server. Edit your php.ini (look at your phpinfo(), "Loaded Configuration File" line, to find the php.ini file path). Find and uncomment the following line (remove the ; character):

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

After this restart the server and should be good to go.

Edit:

```
composer update

composer require doctrine/dbal

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Check your .env file

```
  DB_CONNECTION=mysql
  DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
  DB_PORT=3306
  DB_DATABASE=dbname
  DB_USERNAME=username
  DB_PASSWORD=password
```

run `php -m` and see if it lists pdo

Comment: Thankyou for your response. the line is already uncomment .

Comment: @Reahana Edited it, retry please.

Answer (score 0):

Firest of all, adding **phpinfo** to your code path find out your php.ini location

```
    <?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

[image]

Since you have already uncommented MySQL extension, make sure to uncomment `extension=php_pdo.dll` as well in the **php.ini** and restart the Apache.
Before migration, make sure to run

```
 php artisan cache:clear 
 php artisan view:clear 
 php artisan route:clear
```