# PHP Problem with PDO: could not find driver

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Hello i am trying to build a webapp using oracle DB.
So I created connect.php using **PDO** to access the **Oracle database**. But i get the message: `could not find driver`

So i am using apache2 and in my php.ini this extensions are activated:

`extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client`

`extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client`

`extension=odbc` 
`extension=pdo_firebird`
`extension=pdo_mysql`
`extension=pdo_oci` 
`extension=pdo_odbc`

Maybe i am **missing** some packages or **extensions**? Can u help me out? I my phpinfo i cant find an extra section for oci and i guess thats bad?

I am working on Ubuntuu VM but my database is on another server. I have `Installed PHP 8.1.2`

please help me to eliminate this php error

Comment: Did you install Oracle Instant Client?

Comment: how to install it on ubuntuu VM @ChristopherJones

Comment: wget & unzip from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html  Don't forget to install libaio1 - see the install instructions at the end of that page.

Comment: i installed but i am getting the same issue

Comment: Update your question with the details: if you didn't run `ldconfig` as shown in the instructions you may have issues passing LD_LIBRARY_PATH through the webserver

Answer (score 0):

Just run

> sudo apt install php-mysql

in terminal

Hi I have also faced this issue but this article helped me you no need to edit .ini file just follow this article

[PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: didn´t worked for me