# Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver : sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5

I could run the application, but when database connection needed, I got this error

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
could not find driver
in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.43;Database=RKNandi', 'rajwebuser', 'Rajkumar1', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php line 55
at Connector->createConnection('sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.43;Database=SSSPL', array('driver' => 'sqlsrv', 'host' => '192.168.5.43', 'database' => 'RKNandi', 'username' => 'rajwebuser', 'password' => 'Rajkumar1', 'charset' => 'UTF8', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlsrv'), array('0', '2', '0', false)) in SqlServerConnector.php line 32
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Checkout -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver