# Weird case of notorious error "could not find driver" from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

It looks like my Laravel deliberately ignores API extensions set in my `php.ini` 
 since I’m getting `could not find driver (SQL: select * from ...`.

`php.ini` is configured properly and `php artisan migrate` works fine and I can see its job im my MySQL DB.

Trying to figure out what goes wrong I added phpinfo() into default route and saw this:

`API Extensions = no value
PDO drivers = no value`

However, if I start project by `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` instead of `php artisan serve` the everything works fine and `API Extensions` has `pdo_mysql` and `PDO drivers = mysql`.

In both cases `Loaded Configuration File` is the same `C:\php\php.ini`

What's wrong with Laravel?
PS. Laravel 5.5, php 7.1

Comment: Already Answer given Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Answer (score 0):

<s>Laravel uses the php cli's inbuilt server which can have a different set of enabled extensions than that of the server(fpm or otherwise). Make sure you are editing the correct php.ini this varies on each os and if using linux each distribution. So I can't give the location of your php.ini but there are multiple for any given installation. Usually one for the cli and one for the server bit. The php -S seems to behave the same as using a webserver at least for me</s>

same php.ini is being used

Comment: Nope, actually `php.ini` is the same. I've updated the question.

Comment: That's extremely weird maybe it's an artisan bug have you checked issues on github?