# Laravel migration cannot find driver when using sqlsrv database in windows

Tags: laravel, migration, odbc, sqlsrv

I am using **sqlsrv database** connection in my project as I need to connect to Microsoft SQL Database.

I have successfully installed the **sqlsrv driver** because I can connect to the Database to retrieve data.

But when I try to do the Laravel Migration, it shows an error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)
```

**Below is my .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=**********.database.windows.net
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=****************_4cd1_9d18_2a7d9ddbcd13
DB_USERNAME=***************_4cd1_9d18_2a7d9ddbcd13_ExternalWriter
DB_PASSWORD=***************
```

**php.ini**

```
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll


extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: @SagarGautam, thanks for your comment, I am using Windows OS and  I also have the required PDO extension in my **php.ini** as you can see in the edited.

Answer (score 8):

How to use SQL Server DLL files with PHP 7.2 version on xampp

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

To download Windows DLLs for PHP 7.1 or above from the PECL repository, please go to the SQLSRV or PDO_SQLSRV PECL page.

https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv/5.6.1/windows

https://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv/5.6.1/windows

NOTE: Do not forget to remove 'php_' prefix when you add extension dll filename in php.ini file. eg.

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
extension=sqlsrv
```

Do not change actual filename which you put in /xampp/php/ext/ directory.

"7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x86" worked for me for 'sqlsrv' and 'pdo_sqlsrv' extensions.

Restart xampp or apache then you can see enabled 'pdo_sqlsrv' extension when you print phpinfo() in a test php file

[image]

It was very hard to find this solution. I hope, this will also help you. All the best :)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to **upgrade your PHP version to PHP 7.1.**
Now make sure that the files **config/database.php** and **.env** are configured properly.

See this one: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/connect-laravel-to-microsoft-sql

Comment: My environment already running on PHP 7.1. 
**PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2017 18:34:46)**

Comment: *php_sqlsrv.dll* You need to manually install this extension. Include _extension=php_sqlsrv.dll_ in your php.ini and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

After fighting with it for a while found a solution :

you need to downloaded it from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) then extract the files in your php folder

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 7.4 on Windows 10 (x64), I've solved same error s below:

1. Downloaded the driver from
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
2. Extracted the archive and copied the file
   `php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll` to the `ext` folder (`C:\Program Files\php74\ext` in my setup)
3. Added `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll` into `php.ini` file

In my `.env` file I've `DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv` so I first thought `php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll` should be used but it didn't work.