# Laravel 5.4 on localhost: QueryException could not find driver (SQL: select * from `sessions`

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run laravel 5.4 on localhost php 5.6 using XAMPP with these laravel .env configurations

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname_here
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

But I get **QueryException** could not find driver (SQL: select * from `sessions`

In log file

```
local.ERROR: PDOException: could not find driver in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)
```

But PDO is already installed

I tried to clear the cache but that didn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

[update]

After an edit by changing "SESSION_DRIVER=file" Now I get

```
FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()

local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:78
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\EncryptedStore.php(57): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->encrypt('a:3:{s:6:"_toke...')
```

Comment: in env change  `SESSION_DRIVER=file`

Comment: You may have PDO but have you installed MySQL?

Comment: now I get Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() though extension=php_openssl.dll is not commented @Davit

Comment: @ggdx yes sure it's installed and I can connect to it and imported the database

Comment: that error never happens for me

Comment: did you check the requirements?: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#server-requirements

Comment: also check with php to see what modules are loaded

Comment: openssl is already enabled from phpinfo() and the extension is in the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Might be the issue of missing dependency. Try the following command:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

and also comment-out the following line in your **php.ini** file:

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

[Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240511/7109362)

Also, if you haven't installed **php-mysql** driver, install it with following command (depending on PHP version):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```