# could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I moved my project from my old host to my new host 
I tried some times but every time I tried, Laravel showed this error:

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from `orders` where `status` not
>   in (PENDING, COMPLETED) and `api_order_id` is not null order by RAND() limit 15)

I'm sure I uploaded my database fully and the I put my database information correctly 
So why this error appeared?

Config/database.php codes:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'my_db_name',
            'username' => 'db_user',
            'password' => 'db_pass',
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'modes' => [
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
            ]
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

    'installed' => '1',
    'transfer_mode' => '%transfer_mode%',
];
```

.env file codes:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=db_pass
```

Comment: The issue seems to be that Laravel cannot find the library for connecting to your Database (i.e. could not find driver) - you database might be fine...

Comment: Please give me one more explanation

Comment: Your Laravel-based web application needs files/libraries to handle connection to your database.  Currently, they are not defined/configured so it cannot find them. Hence it cannot connect to the database.

Comment: try to check if your new host has "mysql" first, to check it type "mysql --version", if it exists, try to check your php.ini and uncomment the mysql driver inclusion.

Comment: I checked all of them, they are exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 'could not find driver (SQL: insert into...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486940/laravel-could-not-find-driver-sql-insert-into)

Comment: is your pdo_mysql extension uncommented ?

Comment: No but when I want active it, this error appears : `pdo_mysql skipped as conflicting
`

Comment: I fixed it and I enabled pdo_mysql, but my main problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is the database and php uses extensions  like `pdo_mysql` to connect PHP and MySQL. Firstly driver and extensions are different. Drivers are `mysqlnd` or `mysqlnd` whereas extensions are `pdo_mysql` or `nd_pdo_mysql` etc. First check if drivers are installed properly.

Steps to check fo extensions :

1. Check in `phpinfo()` if you see `pdo_mysql` is enabled.
2. Sometimes managed hosting(mostly ones with cpanel) have their sql extensions enabled by default. Check in phpinto for `_mysql` in php extensions section. Check if you see any other extension enabled like `nd_pdo_mysql`. If it's the case then you will notice a conflict. You need to disable it first and then attempt to enable the `pdo_mysql` again.
3. Restart your PHP service and you can try again if it works.

Comment: Oh, Thank you for your help, I enabled pdo_mysql after unable nd_pdo_mysql. but my main problem not solved and the Laravel error is still there

Comment: What error are you getting now? Is it still the same?

Comment: `could not find driver (SQL: select * from orders where status not in (PENDING, COMPLETED) and api_order_id is not null order by RAND() limit 15)`

Comment: Whats your php version?

Comment: In this script, php v7