# laravel php artisan migrate issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu, pdo, vagrant

When I run this command: `php artisan migrate` I have got an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = loag and
>   table_name = migrations)

I have set up a vagrant environment with **ubuntu 18.04** and PHP, MySQL with versions 7.2. i edited the **php.ini** file and did all of the 1000 things on 100 sites on the web. i'm getting confused that it still don't work to migrate

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname
```

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',//env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => '3306',//env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'loag',//env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => 'root',//env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => 'root',//env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => '/etc/mysql/mysql.sock',//env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

**.env**

```
APP_NAME="Laendliche Ostbahnen AG"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:SKuPKct0ug16L4DTEvcFD59YuHKf8znDmQrqG973L6w=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=loag
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root`
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
...
```

**installation on ubuntu:enter code here**

```
# Set environment variable
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update Packages
apt-get update

# Upgrade Packages
apt-get dist-upgrade

# Apache
apt-get install -y apache2

# Enable Apache Mods
a2enmod rewrite

# Install PHP
apt-get install -y php7.2

# PHP Apache Mod
apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php7.2

# Restart Apache
service apache2 restart

# PHP Mods
apt-get install -y php7.2-xml
apt-get install -y php7.2-common
apt-get install -y php7.2-zip

# PHP-MYSQL lib
apt-get install -y php7.2-mysql
apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Disable old apache vhosts config and enable the new one
#a2dissite 000-default.conf

# Restart Apache
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

DBs in phpmyadmin: (the affected db should be loag(loag and laravel are empty)
information_schema
laravel
loag
mysql
performance_schema
phpmyadmin
sys

need more?

when i do:`php artisan migrate` the following output is generated:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = loag and table_name = migrations)

  at C:\Users\Marco Ris\Desktop\Webdevelopment\loag\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\Users\Marco Ris\Desktop\Webdevelopment\loag\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:unix_socket=/etc/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=loag", "root", "root", [])      C:\Users\Marco Ris\Desktop\Webdevelopment\loag\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details
```

Comment: Are you already enable pdo_mysql module in php.ini?

Answer (score 2):

May be this will solve your problem,

```
sudo apt-get install php7-mysql
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: trust me i did all the things ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver