# Query Exeption error while migrating in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When i am running php artisan migrate there is error like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lara_blog and table_name = migrations)
```

I have already changed my

> AppServiceProvider.php

file. This could not solve that. And I could't find another solution. Please help me solve this problem.

P.S My OS is Linux. I tried to run exactly the same project on Windows, and it is working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: You're missing MySQL for PDO. How did you install PHP on your Linux OS? Using Ondrej Sury's repository or?

Comment: By running  'sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql' , problem was solved. Thank you. @Script47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the mysql extension for php.

In Linux, the install command is 'apt-get install phpX.X-mysql' where the X.X is your php version ('php -v' to find our which version you have).

Comment: Yes I have run 'sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql' and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is general error showing that your system doesn't have database extension (postgres or MySQL whichever you are using) for please try to install it.