# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel

My Laravel Project is working fine on localhost, but when I hosting this on cpanel and try to login or register. it's through me this error like `could not find driver (SQL: select * from`users`where`email`= me@me.com limit 1)`. What Should I do..??

Comment: Did you configure your environment using the .env file? What value did you use for `DB_CONNECTION`?

Comment: Yes, this my connection `DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=nextnir_next
DB_USERNAME=nextnir_nexto
DB_PASSWORD=nextnir@next`

Comment: Are you sure mysql is installed on that environment? Could you add a route that executes `phpinfo();` to further debug this issue?

Comment: Actually  I don't know how to install mysql on live server, and where I find this `phpinfo();` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver) There are already plenty of this type of questions with correct answers that a simple research can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank all of you guys, I find another solution to solve this kind problem, What I have done just in my `.htaccess` file this line of code

`# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
  # Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
   <IfModule mime_module>
     AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
   </IfModule>
  # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit` and change

`DB_USERNAME=something
 DB_PASSWORD=something`

and my problem is solved, this is enabled `mysql` also, Thank you guys Happy Coding....

Answer (score 18):

You probably didn't enable PDO extension.
In your cpanel select

> SOFTWARE > Select PHP Version

You see all extensions there, enable these extensions :

- `pdo`
- `mysqlnd`
- `ndmysqli`
- `nd_pdo_mysql`

Comment: had almost the same problem, nd_pdo_mysql  was not enabled by default in cPanel on the hosting server. Thanks @Mnikoei

Comment: Well done @Mnikoei