# Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, driver

I deploy a laravel project on an apache server on a Debian 10 machine.
The database is an MySQL deployed on another debian 10 machine on the same network.

I can go to the connection interface of the application but when I connect this error appears :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = test@gmail.com limit 1)
```

I have already tried these commands :

```
php artisan migrate
sudo apt install php-mysql
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
sudo systemctl restart apache2
composer require doctrine/dbal
composer update
```

these commands work but do not solve the problem.

and I already tried to comment and uncomment this line in the php.ini :

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

in php-m i have
PDO and pdo-mysql

and i have restart my server with :

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

after modification

Comment: If you run php -m from the command line, does it list pdo? If yes

Comment: have you restarted your php server after comment and UN-comment

Comment: also be sure to both run php artisan -vvv to get more verbose output and check your configured logfile, default storage/log/laravel.log to get more info, there is probably a stack trace that tell more precisley what the error is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547651/illuminate-database-queryexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution
infact the php version used by apache  was 7.3 and not 7.4 with :

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

however when I did:

```
php --version
```

the version was indeed 7.4.
I followed this tutorial to change the version
https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-debian/?amp
and it works

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when running my test suite. It was working before but it stopped working after I upgraded php. So I did and it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem using `php artisan migrate`, there is no problem for the command line to call the php script. If you use fpm and install a new extension, you need to **restart** it and try.

Comment: it might also be helpful to add -vvv to artisan command to get more verbose error information

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error while running Laravel in a docker container.  In my case the issue was that I did not install PDO when building the image.  I solved this by adding the following line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```