# Laravel database error "could not find driver"

Tags: php, database, laravel, postgresql

I am trying to initialize a database in Laravel. For this I am using the command `php artisan db:seed`

It returns the error:

> "Could not find driver".

As seen in this screenshot

[image]

I am using PostgreSQL and my operational system is Windows 10.
Any idea of what could be causing this error?

My **.env** file

```
APP_NAME=Revieway APP_ENV=local 
APP_KEY=base64:xWdLc4KY3iJKHCupluHuu1nDwvpyk4OAqnsc6RRrGsA=
APP_DEBUG=true 
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=localhost:8000
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql 
DB_HOST=192.168.99.100:5050
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=postgres 
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=gghmm 
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log 
CACHE_DRIVER=file 
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: What are the values of your `.env` file? How does your seeder look?

Comment: Hirumina, no. Most answers in this post are considering mysql. I have to use postgresql, which I already have installed.

Comment: APP_NAME=Revieway
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xWdLc4KY3iJKHCupluHuu1nDwvpyk4OAqnsc6RRrGsA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=192.168.99.100:5050
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=gghmm

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

Comment: this is my .env file

Comment: Do you have `php` and `postgresql` installed locally or are you using a virtual machine? If so, you should run the command on the VM.

Comment: Your DB_HOST should not contain  the port: `:5050`

Comment: I have php and postgres installed locally

Comment: I think the DB_HOST is right. I tried removing the port just to be sure, but it doesnt help either.

Answer (score 0):

The PosgreSQL extension must be enabled on your `php.ini` file.

Open it, an change:

```
;extension=pdo_pgsql
```

to:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
```