# Laravel database connection over local network

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, phpstorm

My XAMPP database with MySQL is hosted on the network on a other Windows PC (192.168.1.201). I have access to the database using the browser but cant connect it to the Laravel Framework using PhpStorm.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors, on the screen OR in the error logs?

Comment: C:\Users\Christoph\Google Drive\Studium\Semester 4\Web Tech\pc-konfigurator>php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = pc_konfigurator and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: Does your user account `user` have privilages on database `information_schema`?

Comment: Yes all privilages

Comment: `DB_USERNAME = user` and that has a password of `DB_PASSWORD = root` sure you didnt mean to use the `root` username?

Comment: i tryed to migrate the project i'm working on to the database.

Comment: i'm very sure my friend uses the same database for our git sycronised project :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 PDOException Could Not Find Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: yea mostly thx for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my mac.
Try creating a database-user that accepted all hostnames ("%").