# could not find driver PDOException on aws ubuntu server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my laravel project on ubuntu ec2 instance . When I try to make query thourgh `tinker` it works fine and it return data . But when I try open page it give this error

```
could not find driver
/var/www/html/coldxlogistics/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#70
PDOException
```

I tried many think like.

```
php-mysql
php8.1-mysql
```

are installed on ubuntu

I also tried laravel commands like

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
```

but nothing is working

my php version is `php 8.1.2`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? There are a few suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240414/laravel-5-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver.